# How to save images in r markdown html

Tags: r

So I know how to show images `![Caption](/path/to/image.png)` but I want the image to be saved on the html file so when I open the html file on someone else's computer I should be able to see the image. I will get an error message saying the path is wrong if I try to knit the .Rmd file.

The image is referenced absolutely on my computer but I don't want that. Is there a way to do?

I apologize in advance if this question is a duplicate, but I'm having trouble finding a proper solution. Thanks

Comment: 1. Try to save your document in PDF format. 2. Save with path to image folder ![Caption](images/image.png) and send complete folder with images. 3. Reference image to url (from internet) as an option :)

Comment: the rmd will never embed the png file. Maybe notebooks do? Not sure. But you need to knit into html or pdf. These formats have the png embedded.

Comment: @drmariod Don't know what you're talking about, my knitted html files always contain the images and can be opened everywhere. Embedded with @Aysrealthy's method; right clicking on the image in browser shows this kind of address `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...`. Maybe it's just the wrong path, try knitting by `![Caption](image.png)` with image in same folder as *.Rmd.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to import the image into R and then print it.